# WebView ZoomButtonsController

Tags: android, android-webview

While having "Do not keep activities" option ON in developer settings, I am loading url to webview with `vWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` As a result I am getting followed problem.

```
WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity pl.izmajlowiczl.zoomcontrolls.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container{21639342 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-432,73} that was originally added here (...)
```

After checking ZoomButtonsController code I find out that the problem is posting delayed message on handler which hides zoom controls after some time.

Any ideas how to remove message from ZoomButtonsController's handler when my view destroyes? (It is just private)

Or any other ideas how to solve it?

[ZoomButtonsController class](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ZoomButtonsController.java/?v=source) has mHandler, which handles delayed `MSG_DISMISS_ZOOM_CONTROLS` message

Comment: Please post your code for that Screen

Answer (score 0):

**Cause :** When activity finish is called but the zoom controls are still visible.

**Solution 1:** use pinch zoom

```
// make sure your pinch zoom is enabled
 webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

// don't show the zoom controls
 webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

**Soution 2 :** Add this to your activity:

```
  @Override
    public void finish() {
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.removeAllViews();
        super.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't work if the Activity was killed by the system. Solution 1 seems to be the only workaround for now.